# Dependent proto buffer files produces a "descriptor_table_**_2eproto" has not been declared error

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

So, I am trying to compile a set of `.proto` files with the cmake function `protobuf_generate_cpp`, all of them in the same folder, and some dependent on others. The idea is to create a static library that let me use the messages in other projects.

Let's say I have the following structure in my project:

```
messages-lib/
 |
 +- company
 |    |
 |    +- messages
 |         |
 |         +- Header.proto // dependent on Robot.proto
 |         +- Robot.proto
 |         +- CMakeLists.txt
 +- CMakeLists.txt
```

`Header.proto` imports `Robot.proto` with the following line: `import "company/messages/Robot.proto"` because the idea is to install the library, so any other user should import common messages like that.

However, when I compile the project by using the CMake function provided by Google `protobuf_generate_cpp` it produces the following error:
`project/messages/Header.pb.cc:74:6: error: ‘::descriptor_table_company_2fmessages_2fRobot_2eproto’ has not been declared`

What happend? Looking at the code generated by the CMake function, it seems that for `Robot.pb.h`, it defines a DescriptorTable with the follwing name: `descriptor_table_Robot_2eproto` but then it tries to use `descriptor_table_company_2fmessages_2fRobot_2eproto` in `Header.pb.cc`. Obviously it is not declared.

Another thing that might be important, is that I set `Protobuf_IMPORT_DIRS` in `company/messages/CMakeLists.txt` as the project directory (`messages-lib`), in order to be able to import the proto files as I am currently doing.

Is there a way to solve this issue? (Other than setting all the messages to LITE_RUNTIME optimization, which is not an option since I want to use reflection).

If anyone can help me would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may have `messages-lib/company/messages` in your `Protobuf_IMPORT_DIRS` for some reason. It would cause `protoc` to use that as the base directory, as it always picks the one closest to the file being compiled.

Comment: I realized I was doing an append to `Protobuf_IMPORT_DIRS`. I changed it for a set to the variable, and now it prints the root path: `/home/diego/dev/messages-lib/`. However, the problem persists..

Comment: Ok, I have tried to use protoc directly: `protoc --cpp_out=build/debug --proto_path=/home/diego/dev/messages-lib /home/diego/dev/messages-lib/company/messages/Header.proto /home/diego/dev/messages-lib/company/messages/Robot.proto` and it works fine..